# Misbehaviour by moderators

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Economics Stack Exchange post: [problem of the origin of profit](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/32955/problem-of-the-origin-of-profit)

Excuse me, I have asked a question in economics and mathematics section. Some of the moderators there (not all, but most of them) started attacking me with personal insults. Calling me delusional and stuff. And eventually they have deleted my question.... why? Is there a management here that can look into this? My post was called "problem of the origin of profit". What the point of this website if the moderators attack people and delete their topics with no explanation? I'm talking about moderators like muflon, Don Thousand, EconJohn.
And I don't care about personal insults, they all can consider me to be an idiot or a moron as far as I care, but why delete the post?

Answer (score 4):

I did not comment on your post, but It was unclear what the question was and the context of inclusion of the article you found. It currently seems like a promotion of another websites content which this site (as well as all other stackexchange sites) do not allow. More elaboration on what you are asking as well as providing context for your link (in a way that is not an advertisement) would have had made the post more well received.

I understand the criticism of the moderation and have undeleted your question and have left it up to the other users of the site to vote on its relevance for the community. However It will end up the same regardless as it stands now as the community has voted to close the question.

Also note that the other users you have listed are not moderators so accusations of such abuse by mods should be directed at either [myself or other moderators](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1. so you had 20 hours to tell me to remove that link... which none of you did... I asked specifically if i can add a link...  waited for awhile... nobody answered... so i added. if you want i will remove it.

Comment: 2. what do i care about your community? i'm not offending no one and i have a real topic to discuss...

Comment: what this site for anyway? i didn't come here to make friends

Comment: @James 1) You should note that the moderators on this site are volunteers so the speed of moderation is not a guarantee.2) I dont understand this question, the users of the site determine if the question is relevant for the site. Also this isnt a discussion site, its for specific, largely non-opinionated questions 3) this is a Q&A site for those who study, teach, research and apply economics and econometrics.

Comment: i will edit my question then to make it more understandable. thank you for undeleting it. sorry for being agressive, some people here got under my nerves.

Comment: by the way you want me to remove the link? yes or no? (the link to the medium.com website)

Comment: @James as it looks right now its seems like a promotion for a blog post so yes.

Comment: actually it's my paper on economics... i remove it from the title, but can i mention it in the coments when talking to someone?

Comment: I did what you told me, but it looks like my topic dissappeared from the main page... i changed the title to "How is monetary profit possible in an economy with fixed amount of money?"

Comment: i don't understand... have you undeleted the topic or haven't you? because i can't see it...

Comment: @James it should be undeleted.

Comment: you see it on the list page?

Comment: @James, its probably not as a featured question anymore due to new content coming in and replacing it on the front page

Comment: bro are you playing with me? you have topics there from previous months... you have topics from 6 month ago... comon now.

Comment: tell me, do you have a supervisor? you are doing this on purpose.

Comment: @James The questions that are featured are those that are upvoted and have reoccurring new user engagement. Im not in control of it. The reason why older questions are up is because some new user found it and upvoted it or provided an answer to a question that has been left unanswered for some time. There could be other reasons but i'm not sure.

Comment: Hi James, please refrain from extended conversations in the comments (here and on your original question). Please also note that even if you did not "come here to make friends" you must do your best to be civil according to the code of conduct on this site. Continually making random accusations against people is prohibited. I don't know how you have your front page sorted, but moderators do not have the ability to take things off of a front page or put it on the front page.

Comment: @James this isnt my website

Comment: i will be civil when you leave me alone and let normal people to answer my question... you didn't like the title of my topic, i changed it. what more you want? why do you people even exist?

Comment: why am i talking to you now?

Comment: your job is very simple: a person write a topic, post it, and whoever wants to answer it does it... why do i have to talk to you, and to all the rest useless people here?

Comment: I want to explain to you something, i want to teach you how to exist. the way you exist is not good, you need to stop that. now this is what you do: you let a person to open a topic, and if you have something to contribute then you do that, you say it. If not, then you go away. I didn't go to other people topics here and talked shit there, I minded my business. I opened a topic and i sticked to it. But then all the morons came that have nothing to do, and wasted my time with their crap.

Comment: and in order for the voting system be effective you need normal people to do the voting, but if the majority of people are morons and idiots like on this website, then this system of voting is no good.

Comment: Yes James, you see it clearly. Unfortunately the site cannot be fixed, there are too many morons voting. They will NEVER understand. I recommend simply moving on.

Comment: @Giskard 1. Don't say "they", you are part of "they". When you are a part of "they" then you say "we", you don't say "they".  2. But I don't need YOU to understand, none of you. I have never entered a topic that one of you people created and tried to engage in a conversation with you. You came to me, without me asking you to do that. You are a disturbance, a nuisance, an obstacle for normal people trying to have a civil conversation.